# Dynamically choose type of private member in class

Tags: c++, unit-testing, types, mocking, private-members

I can't get my head around this: I have a class called MyClass, which has a private member of the type MyUsedClass. For creating unit tests I have a simulated (mock) version of the MyUsedClass. I want to dynamically call the MyClass with either a mocked private member of MyUsedClass or the real private member of MyUsedClass. Because I want to call this dynamically, the use of #defines and #ifdefs will not work.

Basically I want to do something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass(bool mock = false) {}; // Default bool to false.
        ~MyClass(void) {};
        void DoSomething(void) { /* Do something with MyUsedObject here... */ };
        void DoMore(void);
        ...
    private:
        if (mock) {
            MyUsedClassMock MyUsedObject;
        } else {
            MyUsedClassReal MyUsedObject;
        }
};

MyClass MyObject; // Create default instance with real MyUsedObject.
MyClass MyObject(true); // Create instance with the mock MyUsedObject.
```

But of course this does not work because one cannot do if statements in the definition of a class.

Another approach was to use polymorphism and create a base class, a real and a mock class. The base class would have all the implementations of all the functions, and by the choice of calling the real or the mock version of MyClass I can choose the type of the MyUsedObject.

```
class MyClassBase {
    public:
        MyClassBase(void) {};
        ~MyClassBase(void) {};
        void DoSomething(void) { /* Do something with MyUsedObject here... */ };
        void DoMore(void);
        ...
    private:
        // No MyUsedObject in the Base class.
};

class MyClassReal : public MyClassBase {
    public:
        MyClassReal(void) {};
        ~MyClassReal(void) {};
    private:
        MyUsedClassReal MyUsedObject; // Here is MyUsedObject created, but then "Real".
};

class MyClassMock : public MyClassBase {
    public:
        MyClassMock(void) {};
        ~MyClassMock(void) {};
    private:
        MyUsedClassMock MyUsedObject; // Here is MyUsedObject created, but then "Mock".
};

MyClassReal MyObject; // Create instance with the real MyUsedObject.
MyClassMock MyObject; // Create instance with the mock MyUsedObject.
```

Unfortunately this also does not work as the MyClassBase function implementations do not know anything about a MyUsedObject yet, so I get errors here. An idea was to use to create a virtual MyUsedObject in the base class, but the problem here is that the base class does not know the type of the object yet (real or mock). Also 'virtual' is not permitted on data declarations, so again I get even more errors once I tried that anyhow.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Useful term for further research: "dependency injection"

Comment: Thanks. I've looked that one up. Did not know that term.

Answer (score 1):

The polymorphic approach is the way to go. However, you'd have to come up with differently:

```
class MyUsedClass { }; // the base class, having (pure?) virtual functions
class MyUsedClassReal : public MyUsedClass { }; // provides real functionality
class MyUsedClassMock : public MyUsedClass { }; // mocks the functionality
```

The deriving classes will provide the implementation specifically needed in real scenario and when mocking. Your own class would now make use of either one or the other dynamically:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(bool mock = false)
    ~MyClass(void) {};
    void doSomething();
private:
    std::unique_ptr<MyUsedClass> myUsedObject;
};

MyClass::MyClass(bool mock)
    : myUsedObject(mock ? new MyUsedClassMock() : new MyUsedClassReal())
{ }

void MyClass::doSomething() { /* use the pointer! */ };
```

If you follow StoryTeller's hint ("dependency injection"), you'd pass the object as argument to the constructor instead of creating it within, which likely is preferrable:

```
MyClass::MyClass(std::unique_ptr<MyUsedClass> object)
    : myUsedObject(std::move(object))
{ }
```

Having a `std::unique_ptr` as parameter as well makes obvious that `MyClass` will grab ownership of the object provided (is a sink for it); this is suitable for your example, not a 'do always' rule, it depends on the use case, in other scenarios a shared pointer (both member and parameter) might be more appropriate.

Comment: Many thanks for the elaborate answer. Very interesting. The `std::unique_ptr` is new for me. I've tried my best to implement this, looked up many other web pages on the topic, but have one remaining question; how would I pass on the object as an argument to the constructor?

Comment: @empewoow Easiest: [`std::make_unique<MyUsedClassReal>(/*parameters for constructor*/)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique). Be aware that there's no problem in assigning smart pointer of derived to smart pointer of base, so that will be fine.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't get it @Aconcagua. I have #included `<memory>` Then I have tried: `std::unique_ptr<MyUsedClass> base_ptr = std::make_unique<MyUsedClassReal>();
MyClass MyObject(base_ptr);` And I get: `error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'base_ptr'` Also I've tried: `MyClass MyObject(std::make_unique<MyUsedClassReal>());` But still get two errors: `overloaded function "std::make_unique" is not a type  name` and `error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'make_unique'` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied (otherwise the pointer wouldn't be unique after copying), so you need: `MyClass myObject(std::move(base_ptr));` note that I already did the same in the constructor. `std::make_unique` is C++14. Do you have C++14 (or C++17) enabled?

Comment: Still I get errors once I try your last solution: `overloaded function "std::move" is not a type name` and `C2061 syntax error: identifier 'move'`. It's weird because it only fails at this last line with `std::move`, while the other line that uses it (`MyClass::MyClass(std::unique_ptr<MyUsedClass> object) : myUsedObject(std::move(object)) {`) does not fail. I'm using Visual Studio 2015, so I think it's using Visual C++ 14.0.

Comment: `std::move` comes with header `<utility>` - have you included it? *'other line'* might have included it indirectly, e. g. via `<vector>`. Could it be that you have your base_ptr declared within the body of an if clause? If using `if`, make sure you have appropriate scope, e. g.: `std::up<Base> b; if(...) { b.reset(new Real()); } else { b.reset(new Mock()); } Myclass c(b);`.

Comment: About language version: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt490614.aspx) and [what's new](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409293.aspx); Question is: which features *are* already implemented (see second link: *'initial support for certain C++14 features'*). `std::make_unique` is a low hanging fruit, so I'd rather assume they included it, but with MS, one never knows... Do you use community edition? Then updating it might be of interest...

Comment: Including `<utility>` did not make a difference, also the lines were not within an if statement. But, it turns out it compiles when I do: `std::unique_ptr<MyUsedClass> base_ptr = std::make_unique<MyUsedClassReal>(); MyClass MyObject(std::move(base_ptr));` or even `MyClass MyObject(std::make_unique<MyUsedClassReal>());` in the *.cpp file as global variable of the class that uses MyClass. (Let's call that one NeedsMyClass.) Earlier I tried loading the MyClass object as a private member of NeedsMyClass. Why doesn't that work? Actually I need it to be there...

Comment: Difficult to say what's going on without seeing the concrete code. How would `NeedsMyClass` include `MyClass`? As pointer? As aggregate member? Did you write a constructor (maybe MSVC has problems without)? `MyClass` probably has no default constructor, so you'd need the to use the constructors initialiser list: `class NMC { std::up<MC> c; NMC() : c(std::make_unique...) /* here! */ { /* not here! */ }`

Comment: Well, it's hard to put in the comment section but basically I'm trying to do this: `class NeedsMyClass {
 public:
  NeedsMyClass(void) {};
  ~NeedsMyClass(void) {};
 private:
  MyClass MyObject(std::make_unique<MyUsedClassReal>());
};` but the MyClass line fails. However when I put the line `MyClass MyObject(std::make_unique<MyUsedClassReal>());` outside the scope of the class definition it compiles without any errors.

Comment: Maybe MSVS doesn't get along with in-class initialisation; try `public: NeedsMyClass(void) : myObject(std::make_unique<...>()) {}; private: MyClass myObject;`.

Comment: I think that was it! It compiles and it works as intended @Aconcagua, thanks again! Now the only thing that bothers me is that the `NeedsMyClass` class needs to include the header of the `MyUsedClassReal` class. While that was not the case when I started this whole issue. At first this was nicely isolated and there was no way `NeedsMyClass` could do anything with a `MyUsedClassReal` (or `Mock`) class. Is this the downside of dependency injection that I just have to deal with?

Comment: Well, new problem here: let this compile at AVR/ARM platforms. On the real setup this code is run on a microcontroller and the PC simulates the code and uses the `Mock` object. I started tackling the issue in Visual Studio and got that working now, but Atmel Studio 7 does not understand `unique_ptr` and `make_unique`... Is there a workaround?

Comment: At very first check if you need to/can enable C++11/14 explicitly in AS (see [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/197022/how-to-enable-c11-support-for-atmel-studio)). If the compiler does not support C++11 at all, you'll have to deal with raw pointers; then don't forget to delete again the object created.